# scope = row not recognised in javascript code (jquery.visualize plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I display a chart but I have to specify that my th column is (scope=row) in javascript code.

The chart used in this manner, Html code (example of using) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="base.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.visualize.plugin.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('table').visualize({type: 'line'}).appendTo('body');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <caption>2009 Employee Sales by Department</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th scope="col">2010</th>
                <th scope="col">2011</th>
                <th scope="col">2012</th>
                <th scope="col">2013</th>
                <th scope="col">2014</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Gastro</th>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Pneumo</th>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Procto</th>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>90</td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that in **tbody**, for the **th** tags, we used **scope="row"**.

I use a datatTable to fill the table and I want to know how to specify it in javascript code.

My javascript code :

```
function fillDataTable(data) {

if ($("#table_campaigns").css("visibility") == "hidden")
    $("#table_campaigns").css("visibility", "visible");

$('#table_campaigns').dataTable({

    'aaData': data,
    'aoColumns': [
        { "sTitle": "", "sCellType": "th", "fnCreatedCell": function (cell) { cell.scope = 'row';}},
        { "sTitle": "2010" },
        { "sTitle": "2011" },
        { "sTitle": "2012" },
        { "sTitle": "2013" },
        { "sTitle": "2014" }
    ],

    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
}
```

I tested too **$(tbody>th).attr('scope','row')** but in vain.

Here is my chart :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works for me:

```
$('table tbody th').attr('scope','row');
```

You only want to use `>` when looking for direct childrens. `th` is not a direct children of `tbody`.
Also, you need to add quotes.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbP7s/)

Comment: I added after filling my dataTable and I have the same chart.
I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jayce as you can see in my example by using a DOM inspector, the code I provided works correctly. You might have other problem then. My code adds the `scope ="row"` attribute on the `th` as you requested.

Comment: You should accept this answer and ask another question as this one is already resolved.